# How to change the phrase "the way" to an actual "thing"?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am writing the following:

> Every single aspect of drones - the mechanical whir of their propellers, the way they gracefully zoom hundreds of feet into the air, the complex sensors that effortlessly stabilize the camera – absolutely mesmerizes me.

I am trying to find a way to reword the phrase "the way they gracefully zoom hundreds of feet into the air" to not use "the way", but instead an actual thing, like whir or sensors. Basically I am looking for a word that describes the flight of a drone.

Comment: ... their graceful zoom ...

Comment: You apparently mean to say "the (gracefulness) in zooming ...." You would rather consider a close synonym like the **pretty agility**, the **sheer elegance** etc.

Comment: One thing that might help, is *why* do you want to change "the way"? It sounds perfectly natural to me, not to mention well written. To help change it, it would be helpful to know what the sentence needs to do that it isn't doing now.

Comment: Learn how to write poetry.

Comment: as @Kris suggests - "their graceful flight" or "their grace as they zoom"

Comment: You may consider (also) posting this on the [Writing StackExchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I got this, but I'll try:

> Every single aspect of drones - the mechanical whir of their
>   propellers, **their ability to swiftly soar into the sky**, the
>   complex sensors that effortlessly stabilize the camera – absolutely
>   mesmerizes me.

I was also thinking along the lines "ascending".

Comment: ... the mechanical whir of their propellers, their gracefully zooming hundreds of feet into the air and the complex sensors that effortlessly ...